# pipeline trigger paths filter error: Unexpected value 'paths'

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines

Trying an example to trigger a pipeline using path filters.

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: parentpipeline
    source: 'parent-pipeline' 
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
      paths:
        include:
        - scripts/*

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1  
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

I have a following folder structure in a sample repo, and paths filter throwing an error `/pipeline-depenedent.yml (Line: 16, Col: 7): Unexpected value 'paths'`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rlAd.png)

tried wrapping include value text around quotes, with and without branches filter. Can't understand what's wrong in the template above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported on this level:

```
  paths:
    include:
    - scripts/*
```

Check this link for the trigger: [resources.pipelines.pipeline.trigger definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline-trigger?view=azure-pipelines)

> **enabled boolean.**
>
> Whether the trigger is enabled; defaults to true.
>
> **branches resources.pipelines.pipeline.trigger.branches.**
>
> Branch names to include or exclude for triggering a run.
>
> **stages string list.**
>
> List of stages that when matched will trigger the
> pipeline.
>
> **tags string list.**
>
> List of tags that when matched will trigger the
> pipeline.

Comment: thank you for quick reply. Isn't it the documentation say paths are supported from the following link : https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md

Comment: @user16843777 there is a slight difference in your sample and the documentation. You are trying to use pipelines as a trigger but the documentation describes repository trigger in which you can use `path`